# How do you get the name of the oldest person using split strings and array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I've been staring at this problem for too long.. This is an exercise from https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-3/4-using-strings and I have to get the name of the oldest person through splitting the strings and finding the name with the oldest age.

```
> Sample Input: Johnny, 5
>               Rose, 19
>               Sam, 10
```

Desired Output: Rose

Any help would genuinely be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameOfTheOldest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name = "";

        while (true) {

            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            if (input.equals("")) {

                break;

            }

            String[] pieces = input.split(",");

            int age = Integer.valueOf(pieces[1]);

            int oldest = 0;

            if (age > oldest) {

                name = pieces[0];

                oldest = age;

            }
        }

        System.out.println("Name of the oldest: " + name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed the variable declaration for `oldest` inside of the loop, so each time that a new line of input is read, `oldest` is set back to 0, if you move that outside of the while loop, your code should work properly as is.

Answer (score 1):

[Snippet of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px98q.png)

Folks who are still looking for the answer, here I am attaching the source code below for your reference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameOfTheOldest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int old=0;
        String s="";
        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            String[] part = input.split(",");
            //String name = part[0];                            
            int age = Integer.valueOf(part[1]);
            if (age>old) {
                old=age;
                s = part[0];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Name of the oldest: "+s);
    } }
```